# Implement Oauth2.0 Authorization Server and ResourceServer as seperate RestFul API's running on two different servers,

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, authorization, spring-security-oauth2

Most of the tutorials in order to implement authorization server guide to use @EnableResourceServer on the main method.

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/03/12/oauth2-spring-security-guide

https://dzone.com/articles/build-an-oauth-20-authorization-server-with-spring

but already have a Controller and a set of endpoint in other project module deployed as a war.
I just need to implement Authorization server as an api rather than a stand alone application. which will be called by a third party api.

Comment: @Rites you have any views on the problem?

Comment: Did you try Keycloak?